# Problems with a POST/PUT Json RESTful request Grails

Tags: json, grails, post, request, put

Hi I have a grails restful code. I do perfect a Json get and delete request.
My problem is:
I want to do a Put or post request with json but if I use a program to do that It has an error and I cant do it!
Here my code:
  One class:

```
package catalogo.json
class Catalogo {
   String nombre
   String descripcion
   String url
   Set <Parametros>parametros =[]
   static hasMany = [parametros:Parametros]
   int numeroParametros = parametros.size()
}
```

And other class:

```
package catalogo.json

class Parametros {
   String tipoParametro
   String json
   static constraints = {
     tipoParametro(nullable:true)
     json(nullable:true)
   }
}
```

I don't know how to put my json in the request. Heres the error when I put it.

**EXAMPLE:**
I PUT POST request.
    body `application/json` (or `text/json` is the same error)  Charset-utf-8

```
{"descripcion": "bla", "nombre" : "lalala", "numeroParametros":3, "parametros":[{                 
"tipoParametro":"string", "json":"bla"}],"url":"http://www.google.com"}
```

And here the error:

```
Could not create new Catalogo due to errors:
 grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 3 errors
Field error in object 'catalogo.json.Catalogo' on field 'descripcion': rejected value [null]; codes [catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion.nullable.error.catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion,catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion.nullable.error.descripcion,catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion.nullable.error.java.lang.String,catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion.nullable.error,catalogo.descripcion.nullable.error.catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion,catalogo.descripcion.nullable.error.descripcion,catalogo.descripcion.nullable.error.java.lang.String,catalogo.descripcion.nullable.error,catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion.nullable.catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion,catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion.nullable.descripcion,catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion.nullable.java.lang.String,catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion.nullable,catalogo.descripcion.nullable.catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion,catalogo.descripcion.nullable.descripcion,catalogo.descripcion.nullable.java.lang.String,catalogo.descripcion.nullable,nullable.catalogo.json.Catalogo.descripcion,nullable.descripcion,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [descripcion,class catalogo.json.Catalogo]; default message [La propiedad [{0}] de la clase [{1}] no puede ser nulo]
Field error in object 'catalogo.json.Catalogo' on field 'nombre': rejected value [null]; codes [catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre.nullable.error.catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre,catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre.nullable.error.nombre,catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre.nullable.error.java.lang.String,catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre.nullable.error,catalogo.nombre.nullable.error.catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre,catalogo.nombre.nullable.error.nombre,catalogo.nombre.nullable.error.java.lang.String,catalogo.nombre.nullable.error,catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre.nullable.catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre,catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre.nullable.nombre,catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre.nullable.java.lang.String,catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre.nullable,catalogo.nombre.nullable.catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre,catalogo.nombre.nullable.nombre,catalogo.nombre.nullable.java.lang.String,catalogo.nombre.nullable,nullable.catalogo.json.Catalogo.nombre,nullable.nombre,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [nombre,class catalogo.json.Catalogo]; default message [La propiedad [{0}] de la clase [{1}] no puede ser nulo]
Field error in object 'catalogo.json.Catalogo' on field 'url': rejected value [null]; codes [catalogo.json.Catalogo.url.nullable.error.catalogo.json.Catalogo.url,catalogo.json.Catalogo.url.nullable.error.url,catalogo.json.Catalogo.url.nullable.error.java.lang.String,catalogo.json.Catalogo.url.nullable.error,catalogo.url.nullable.error.catalogo.json.Catalogo.url,catalogo.url.nullable.error.url,catalogo.url.nullable.error.java.lang.String,catalogo.url.nullable.error,catalogo.json.Catalogo.url.nullable.catalogo.json.Catalogo.url,catalogo.json.Catalogo.url.nullable.url,catalogo.json.Catalogo.url.nullable.java.lang.String,catalogo.json.Catalogo.url.nullable,catalogo.url.nullable.catalogo.json.Catalogo.url,catalogo.url.nullable.url,catalogo.url.nullable.java.lang.String,catalogo.url.nullable,nullable.catalogo.json.Catalogo.url,nullable.url,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [url,class catalogo.json.Catalogo]; default message [La propiedad [{0}] de la clase [{1}] no puede ser nulo]
```

EDIT HERE MY CONTROLLER:

```
package catalogo.json

import grails.converters.JSON

class CatalogoController {

 def index = {       
 switch(request.method){
   case "POST":
        def catalogo = new Catalogo(params.catalogo)
        if(catalogo.save()){
          response.status = 201 // Created
          render catalogo as JSON
        }
        else{
          response.status = 500 //Internal Server Error
          render "Could not create new Airport due to errors:\n                                                          
                      ${catalogo.errors}"
        }
        break
  case "GET":
  if(params.id){render Catalogo.findById(params.id) as JSON}
  else{render Catalogo.list() as JSON}          
  break
 case "PUT":
 def catalogo = Catalogo.findById(params.catalogo.id)
  catalogo.properties = params.catalogo
  if(catalogo.save()){
    response.status = 200 // OK
    render catalogo as JSON
  }
  else{
    response.status = 500 //Internal Server Error
    render "Could not create new Catalogo due to errors:\n ${catalogo.errors}"
  }
  break     
  case "DELETE":
  if(params.id){
    def catalogo = Catalogo.findById(params.id)
    if(catalogo){
      catalogo.delete()
      render "Successfully Deleted."
    }
    else{
      response.status = 404 //Not Found
      render "${params.id} not found."
    }
  }
  else{
    response.status = 400 //Bad Request
    render """DELETE request must include the ID code
              Example: /rest/catalogo/id
    """
   }
    break
  }
}
  def list = {
  if(!params.max) params.max = 10
  def list = Catalogo.list(params)
  withFormat{
    html{
      return [catalogoList:list]
    }
    json{
      render list as JSON
    }
  }
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you saving `Catalogo` in controller?

Comment: watch the update :) thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is how it should be done in controllers:-

```
def index() {
    //JSON Object is not bound to params it is bound to request in POST/PUT
    def jsonObj = request.JSON

    //You can also use JSON.parse() to get a JSON object if the request payload has JSON as string
    //def jsonObj = JSON.parse(request)

    //You will not be able to save the inner JSONArrays if you
    // directly bind the jsonObj to the domain. in order to save
    //convert them to the proper domain objects otherwise you would get validation     errors for parametros
    def catalogParams = [] as Set
    jsonObj.parametros.each{
        catalogParams << new CatalogParams(it)
    }

    //Set the domain back to the jsonObj
    jsonObj.parametros = catalogParams

    //Bind to catalog
    def catalog = new Catalog(jsonObj) 
    //Synonymous to new Catalog(params) but here you cannot use params.

    //Save
    if (!catalog.save(flush: true)){
        catalog.errors.each {
            println it
        }
    }

    render catalog
}

//Domain Classes:-
class CatalogParams {
    String tipoParametro
    String json
    static constraints = {
        tipoParametro(nullable:true)
        json(nullable:true)
    }
}

class Catalog {
    String nombre
    String descripcion
    String url
    Set<CatalogParams> parametros = []
    static hasMany = [parametros: CatalogParams]
    int numeroParametros = parametros.size()
}
```

**REST Client:**

How are you testing the REST WS? You should have a REST client to test the service? Or you can use [REST console extension in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) to test your service. You can also use a grails plugin [rest-client-builder](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) to test your service. In basic terms, if you do not want any client implementation then atleast a script to test your service. [HttpBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/post.html) will be useful in this case:. Something like this is required to test your service

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://yourdomain.com/catalog/')
http.request(POST, JSON) {
  requestContentType = ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON // coreesponding to application/json
  body = ["descripcion": "bla", "nombre" : "lalala", "numeroParametros":3, "parametros":[{ "tipoParametro":"string", "json":"bla"}],"url":"google.com"]

  response.success = { resp ->
    assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
  }
}
```

Comment: in the update,here my controller.I only want to know how to put the json in the request.its not about the code its about this json to do the request in a resful client to try it.

Comment: Whichever REST client you use, just set the json as `request.JSON = "your json here"`, you should be able to access the JSON the way I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: But if I put this JSON request, I have 505 error and I know know why.What I have to change,please?   {"descripcion": "bla", "nombre" : "lalala", "numeroParametros":3, "parametros":[{                 
"tipoParametro":"string", "json":"bla"}],"url":"http://www.google.com"} Where I put request.JSON="your json here"???? in the controller?In the client??THANKS

Comment: See my update, and visit all the link I added to get an idea how a RESTful service can be tested.