# Saving hasMany relationship without addTo

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, has-many

we have two domain classes

```
class FeeGroup {

String name;

static hasMany = [priceRanges:PriceRange]
```

and

```
class PriceRange {

Integer from;
Integer to;
Boolean include;

static belongsTo = [feeGroup:FeeGroup]
```

From my frontend application I receive form as JSON

```
{
    "name":"fee group 1",
    "priceRanges":[
                    {"from":10, "to":20, "include":true},
                    {"from":20, "to":40, "include":true},
                    {"from":30, "to":60, "include":true}
                  ]
}
```

Right now I want to save all data simple

```
def model = new FeeGroup(data)
model.save()
```

With this code shoud be saved also priceRanges. What is wrong with this? Because this save just FeeGroup! Wierd is when you

```
println model.priceRanges
```

after model.save() it will print also new IDs of PriceRanges - but nothing is in database and also not in Hibernate (flush not helped here).

Everywhere in Documentations is that I should use model.AddToPriceRanges but why? Why one-to-one is working perfectly and one-tp-many not?

I already tried changed FeeGroup domain class to

```
class FeeGroup {

String name;
Set priceRanges
static hasMany = [priceRanges:PriceRange]
```

and right now is simple saving working perfectly but GORM created one connection table fee_group_price_range... I dont want to have 3 tables for hasMany connection. It is not good solution.

Thanks for advice

**EDIT**

3 tables is not because of changes in FeeGroup Class but because change PriceRange Class to

```
class PriceRange {

Integer from;
Integer to;
Boolean include;

static belongsTo = FeeGroup
```

Comment: Hope [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16826593/2051952) can be of any help.

Comment: This is solution but not nice... Updating is messy because you need to check old items with new items, compare which items are new, which items are changed and which items missing in new items(should be deleted).

Comment: Because of this Grails bug we move our project to Java EE 7. You need write more in Java EE 7 but everything working as you expect.